# JQuery two forms toggled, show correct form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two forms being toggled as shown below. What I need to figure out, is how to show the correct form once it has been submitted and page refreshed. It will default to the lookup_form only currently. I have been browsing the internet for answers, but am not finding any good examples.

```
  <div class="lookup_form">
    <form method="POST" action="" id="lookup_form"></form>
  </div>
  <div class="nolookup_form">
  <form method="POST" action="" id="nolookup_form"></form>
  </div>
    <a href="#" class="show"> //Firing off the script      

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".nolookup_form").hide();
            $(".show").click(function(){
            $(".lookup_form, .nolookup_form").slideToggle("slow, linear");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Essentially I need to always show after refresh the actual form that was submitted.

Comment: `lookup_form` and `nolookup_form` are IDs so use `#` instead of `.` in the selector

Comment: What is in the 2 forms? Why do you need to show the "other" form after submit?

Comment: From your code, you are showing the `#lookup_form` by default. What exactly do you want to acheive? What are you clicking on to 'toggle' the form?

Comment: Oh, now with your edit my previous comment is no more relevant. That's why it's important to include **all** the relevant code

Comment: Revised code to show better how it is being used. I need to show the form again IF there are errors. I am catching and showing the errors, but the second form, nolookup_form isn't showing.

Comment: Essentially I need to always show after refresh the actual form that was submitted.

Comment: So as @gaetanoM suggested in their answer, inside the `click` event you should save the relevant form id: `localStorage.setItem("formId", $(this).children('form').attr('id'));` and the you can use it to toggle the correct form - `localStorage.getItem("formId") ? $('.' + localStorage.getItem("formId") ).slideToggle("slow, linear") : jQuery.noop();`

Comment: Wonderful, I will implement now.

Comment: I would say use sessionStorage instead of localStorage, and remember to clear your localStorage/sessionStorage on page unload event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you know what form you should show at the backend that produces your page, you can just pass that to javascript

```
<script>
var showForm2 = <?php echo $shouldShow2ndForm?'true':'false'; ?>;

if( showForm2 ){
    //hide form1 and show form2
} else {
    //hide form2 and show form1
}
</script>
```

Comment: I added the variables to my submit form function for the respective form.

Comment: You can skip all the js code and just add a `hidden` class the same way.

`<div class="lookup_form <?php echo $shouldShow2ndForm?'hidden':''; ?>">`

and

`<div class="nolookup_form <?php echo $shouldShow2ndForm?'':'hidden'; ?>">`

Answer (score 1):

You may use cookie or [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage):

before submitting the form you can save the form id for example with:

```
localStorage.setItem("formId", "lookup_form");
```

and on dom ready you can test the value of this:

```
localStorage.getItem("formId")
```

An example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //
    // on DOM Ready get formId from localstorage
    //
    var formId = localStorage.getItem("formId");
    if (formId == null) { // never set: set the default value
        formId = 'nolookup_form';
        localStorage.setItem("formId", formId);
    }

    //
    // Hide the other form
    //
    $("form:not(#" + formId + ")").hide();


    //
    // on form submit save in localstorage current form id
    //
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem("formId", this.id);
    });

    $("#show").on('click', function(e) {
        $("#lookup_form, #nolookup_form").slideToggle("slow, linear");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" action="" id="lookup_form">
    <p>First form</p>
    <button type="submit">Submit lookup</button>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="" id="nolookup_form">
    <p>Second form</p>
    <button type="submit">Submit nolookup</button>
</form>

<button type="button" id="show">Show</button>
```

Comment: Wonderful code @gaetanoM, This post will be a helpful reference, for others in similar situations, to have some options. :)